# Are locked pages inherited by pthreads?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, paging

I have a little paging problem on my realtime system, and wanted to know how exactly linux should behave in my particular case.

Among various other things, my application spawns 2 threads using pthread_create(), which operate on a set of shared buffers.
The first thread, let's call it A, reads data from a device, performs some calculations on it, and writes the results into one of the buffers.
Once that buffer is full, thread B will read all the results and send them to a PC via ethernet, while thread A writes into the next buffer.

I have noticed that each time thread A starts writing into a previously unused buffer, i miss some interrupts and lose data (there is an id in the header of each packet, and if that increments by more than one, i have missed interrupts).
So if i use n buffers, i get exactly n bursts of missed interrupts at the start of my data acquisition (therefore the problem is definitely caused by paging).

To fix this, i used mlock() and memset() on all of the buffers to make sure they are actually paged in.
This fixed my problem, but i was wondering where in my code would be the correct place do this. In my main application, or in one/both of the threads? (currently i do it in both threads)

According to the libc documentation (section 3.4.2 "Locked Memory Details"), memory locks are not inherited by child processes created using fork().
So what about pthreads? Do they behave the same way, or would they inherit those locks from my main process?

Some background information about my system, even though i don't think it matters in this particular case:

- It is an embedded system powered by a SoC with a dual-core Cortex-A9 running Linux 4.1.22 with PREEMPT_RT.
- The interrupt frequency is 4kHz
- The thread priorities (as shown in htop) are -99 for the interrupt, -98 for thread A (both of which are higher than the standard priority of -51 for all other interrupts) and -2 for thread B

**EDIT:**

I have done some additional tests, calling my page locking function from different threads (and in main).

If i lock the pages in main(), and then try to lock them again in one of the threads, i would expect to see a large amount of page faults for main() but no page faults for the thread itself (because the pages should already be locked). However, htop tells a different story: i see a large amount of page faults (MINFLT column) for each and every thread that locks those pages.

To me, that would suggest that pthreads actually do have the same limitation as child processes spawned using fork(). And if this is the case, locking them in both threads (but not in main) would be the correct procedure.

Comment: Threads use the same address space and page tables, so locks should be common.

Comment: It seems they are not... I have added my new findings to my initial post

Comment: Please show the lock calls for main and the threads.  Are you sure you are using the same addresses?

Comment: Okay, so i tried to create a simplified minimal example of my problem, and that one behaved exactly as it should. I also checked the addresses on my actual application, but they are definitely the same for all threads. I have no idea how this can happen, since i don't ever unlock any pages (so my application should behave exactly the same as the minimal example). Of course, my application is way bigger, both in terms of code size as well as memory consumption, but that really shouldn't affect any of this

Comment: After locking in main are you sure the page faults in the thread aren't from the code being paged in?

Comment: Pretty sure, for two reasons: 1. the number of page faults matches the total buffer size, and 2. the page faults only appear on threads that call my locking function. I guess that suggests there is some bug somewhere in my application (otherwise the minimal example should have shown the same behavior), but i have no idea how i would even go about debugging something like that (unless there's some way to intercept those page faults in my code?)

Answer (score 1):

Threads share the same memory management context.  If a page is resident for one thread, it's resident for all threads in the same process.

The implication of this is that memory locking is per-process, not per-thread.

You are probably still seeing minor faults on the first write because a fault is used to mark the page dirty.  You can avoid this by also writing to each page after locking.

Comment: That doesn't match my observations though. My locking function actually does a memset() on each buffer after locking it (to make 100% sure it is paged in), which seems to create a lot of page faults. That is exactly what i expected and totally fine for my program, because it happens only once at the start. However, i get those page faults for each thread, not just the first one to lock the pages. And, most importantly, the number of faults is the same for all the threads (and matches the size of my buffers).